# Opposite of "where in"

Tags: mysql

i would like ask you if exist a command that do the opposite of WHERE IN, i want select all the row with different pamaters of an array.

```
<?php
 $data = array(1,2,3);
 // normal query
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id <> 1 && id <> 2 && id <> 3";
 // how can i do the same query passing an array?

?>
```

Comment: `WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2,3)` ? oO Try `EXISTS()` also and `NOT EXISTS()`

Comment: Should `NULL` values be returned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use `NOT` before any validation in SQL to get the opposite of it.

In your case it would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 
WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 
WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3)
```